# Creating question within question within question in Survey123 Connect

Tags: arcgis-survey123

What I am trying to do is:

Question 1: What fruit do you like? (checkbox answers)

A: Apples
B: Bananas
C: Cherries

when one of the answers is picked, more questions are revealed. For example, if apples is picked:

Question 2: What type of apples do you like?

A: Braeburn
B: MacIntosh
C: Delicious
D: Other

If other is picked, have a text box appear asking for an input

I got the first cascade part down (second question revealed when a choice is picked), but I don't know how to get the "other" text box to appear when that is picked, i.e. a question within a question within a question.

Answer (score 1):

In the third question's "Relevant" column, enter an expression that defines when that question should be displayed (ie, is relevant).

See:  https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformexpressions.htm

For your particular case, I reckon you'd want to use an expression something like:  `selected(${apple_type_question}, 'Other')`